# Portainer endpoint over ssh

Tags: docker, ssh, portainer

I have a server with docker containers and with only ssh access to it.

I can not connect to it over http or etc.

I can not add more network ports available, except 22(and 22 is already occupied by ssh).

I have portainer, running on my local PC.

So. Is there a way i can add endpoint in portainer, to work with this servers containers over ssh?

Answer (score 3):

I am also searching for a solution to this and the solution [masseyb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64033386/portainer-endpoint-over-ssh#answer-64035811) can be extended for persistence in a couple of ways:

1. autossh
2. systemd service file
3. run ssh from a local docker container -- unsure on this one, I'm quite new to docker

<strike>Instead of starting portainer directly you can just add the environment in the portainer web interface (Environments -> create Environment). This is pretty much a requirement for these methods.</strike>

EDIT: portainer needs to be started with the port forwarding or with `--network host` so it can see the exposed port or with `-v /var/run/docker-$${HOST}.sock:/var/run/docker-$${HOST}.sock` so it can see the unix socket.

Autossh is a straightfoward method, just replace `ssh` with `autossh` and you are done.

For use with systemd: Here is a unit file I use for creating **reverse tunnels**, *but it can easily be adjusted for local->remote tunneling by changing -R to -L (and optionally changing the description)*:

```
    [Unit]
    Description=A reverse tunnel using ssh for %I (format remote port:host:local port, connect to host forward remote port to local port)
    Wants=network-online.target
    After=network-online.target
    StartLimitIntervalSec=0
    
    [Service]
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'URI=%i; REMOTE_PORT=$${URI%%%%:*}; LOCAL_PORT=$${URI##*:}; HOST=$${URI%:*}; HOST=$${HOST#*:}; /usr/bin/ssh -qNnT -o ServerAliveInterval=30  -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i /etc/rtunnel/$${HOST}.id_rsa -R $$REMOTE_PORT:localhost:$$LOCAL_PORT sshdummy@$$HOST'
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=60
    
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To set this up:

1. save as something like /lib/systemd/system/rtunnel@.service on localhost
2. adjust parameters as needed (change -R to -L for local->remote port forwarding)
3. create a separate user on the server (mine is called sshdummy).
4. create a password-less ssh key pair on localhost, save private key in `/etc/rtunnel/${host}.id_rsa` and copy public id to `sshdummy@host:~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
5. run `sudo systemctl enable --now rtunnel@10022:myhost:22` on your host (This creates a persistent tunnel from myhost:10022 to localhost:22)

- optional for 3.: set user's login shell to /bin/cat (for extra security)
- optional for 3.: add rule in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for user so the ClientAliveInterval and ClientAliveCountMax values are set too:

```
Match User sshdummy
  ClientAliveInterval 15
  ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

explanation of ssh and systemd options:

`StartLimitIntervalSec=0` stops systemd from killing the service if it fails to start after X seconds

`Restart=always` ensures the service is always restarted after `RestartSec=60` seconds

`-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes` ensures that ssh exits and thus the service restarts when the tunnel can't be set up

`-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` disregard host key validation failures

`-i /etc/rtunnel/$${HOST}.id_rsa` use a separate ssh key for every host you want to connect to

Answer (score 2):

If you're permitted to forward connections you could forward a local socket connection to the remote server over `ssh` then run `portainer` locally bind-mounting that socket:

```
ssh -n -N -T -L ${PWD}/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock user@host &
docker run -d \
    -p 8000:8000 \
    -p 9000:9000 \
    --name=portainer \
    --restart=always \
    -v ${PWD}/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v portainer_data:/data \
    portainer/portainer-ce
```

Comment: Yes, not bad.

This can be quite suitable in case of one server.

But if you have more than one, it becomes a little uncomfortable )

Besides that ssh connection breaks in case of inactivity.

But if there is no other variants, I should use this.

Thank you for this variant

Comment: (1) there's no mention of multiple servers in the question and (2) there's only so much you can do when all you have available is `ssh`, e.g. implies that whatever you're going to do is over `ssh` so it boils down to what's possible using `ssh`. You can set the `-oServerAliveInterval=300 -oServerAliveCountMax=5` `ssh` connection options to try and keep the connection alive.

Comment: Could run `portainer` instances on each remote server and forward TCP connections if you prefer but still 1 `ssh` connection to forward the traffic for each remote server (with all the pitfalls of using `ssh`). I wouldn't suggest this.

Comment: Yes, your answer seems to be the only solution.
I hoped there is any  other solution, builded in portainer agent or etc, that could work over ssh out of the box.